# How to map with Automapper depending on a variable?

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, automapper

(automapper 9)

I am trying to conditionally map. In other words - depending on a variable in my controller (`lang`) to pick different field from the model (`NameEnglish` vs `NameFrench`). The variable is not part of the model at all, so something like this

`.ForMember(dest => dest.baz, opt => opt.Condition(src => (src.baz >= 0)));`

doesn't help me, as I need an outside variable.

From documentation it looks like I have to use a `ValueResolver`. I tried this:

```cs
// Controller
var catDtos = _mapper.Map<List<Category>, List<CategoryGetDTO>>(cats, opt => opt.Items["lang"] = "en");

// DTO
public class CustomResolver : IValueResolver<Category, CategoryGetDTO, string>
    {
        public string Resolve(Category source, CategoryGetDTO destination, string member, ResolutionContext context)
        {
            return context.Items["lang"] == "en" ? source.NameEnglish : source.NameFrench;
        }
    }

// mapper
...
 .ForMember(x => x.Name, opt => opt.MapFrom<CustomResolver>())
...
```

I can't seem to find the right overload and structure it correctly. Source says:

```cs
void MapFrom<TValueResolver, TSourceMember>(Expression<Func<TSource, TSourceMember>> sourceMember) where TValueResolver : IMemberValueResolver<TSource, TDestination, TSourceMember, TMember>;
void MapFrom<TValueResolver>() where TValueResolver : IValueResolver<TSource, TDestination, TMember>;
void MapFrom(IValueResolver<TSource, TDestination, TMember> valueResolver);
void MapFrom<TSourceMember>(IMemberValueResolver<TSource, TDestination, TSourceMember, TMember> valueResolver, Expression<Func<TSource, TSourceMember>> sourceMember);
void MapFrom<TValueResolver, TSourceMember>(string sourceMemberName) where TValueResolver : IMemberValueResolver<TSource, TDestination, TSourceMember, TMember>;
```

It would be great to have a little tip on how to set this up. Thanks!

Also, if there is a more meaningful way, to achieve that, I am open to suggestions.

Comment: Use a `Func` based overload.

Comment: How can I do that? Can you show me?

Comment: There are many examples available in the AM repo and elsewhere online.